# PhantomJS Segmentation fault

Tags: php, laravel, phantomjs, casperjs

I use casperjs and phantom js in laravel

```
putenv('PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE='.config('hs.PHANTOMJS'));
$js_path = \resource_path('assets/js/main.js');
$jquery_path = \base_path('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
$link = 'www.example.com';
$response = shell_exec(config('hs.CASPERJS').' ' . $js_path . ' "' . $link . '" "' . $jquery_path . '"');
```

I run this code on another server and all was OK

But now I run it on just created new server and get Segmentation fault message

I try run

```
/var/www/myuser/data/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs --version
```

And get the same error
But on another server all works fine

Answer (score 0):

To solve problem I move phantomjs file to /var/www and its work fine